# Population calculation per grid using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, population

I have a ward map of a city along with the population in each ward.  I have divided the map into 1 km* 1 km grids.

How do I calculate the population per grid, taking into account that there can be more than 1 ward in each grid?

Comment: Do you have raster or vector data of the population?

Comment: have a look at these related questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/214893/81764
https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/53081/81764